# Coding Competitions: How to store large numbers and find its all combination modulus P

Tags: c++, math, combinations, modulus, largenumber

I have started doing competitive programming and most of the time i find that the input size of numbers is like

```
     1 <= n <=  10^(500).
```

So i understand that it would be like 500 digits which can not be stored on simple int memory. I know c and c++.

I think i should use an array. But then i get confused on how would i find

```
   if ( (nCr % P) == 0 )  //for all (0<=r<=n)//
```

I think that i would store it in an array and then find nCr. Which would require coding multiplication and division on digits but what about modulus.

Is there any other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you don't want to code the multiplication and division yourself, but use something like the GNU MP Bignum library http://gmplib.org/

Comment: I guess the online judges won't be allowing these libraries to be used..instead [this](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/3869/best-known-algos-for-calculating-ncr-m) can be helpful ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding large number libraries, I have used [ttmath](http://www.ttmath.org/), which provides arbitrary length integers, floats, etc, and some really good operations, all with relatively little bulk.

However, if you are only trying to figure out what (n^e) mod m is, you can do this for very large values of e even without extremely large number calculation. Below is a function I added to my local ttmath lib to do just that:

```
/*!
        mod power this = (this ^ pow) % m
        binary algorithm (r-to-l)

        return values:
        0 - ok
        1 - carry
        2 - incorrect argument (0^0)
    */
    uint PowMod(UInt<value_size> pow, UInt<value_size> mod)
    {
        if(pow.IsZero() && IsZero())
        // we don't define zero^zero
        return 2;

        UInt<value_size> remainder;
        UInt<value_size> x = 1;

        uint c = 0;

        while (pow != 0)
        {
            remainder = (pow & 1 == 1);
            pow /= 2;
            if (remainder != 0)
            {
                c += x.Mul(*this);
                x = x % mod;                                
            }

            c += Mul(*this);
            *this = *this % mod;        
        }

        *this = x;
        return (c==0)? 0 : 1;
    }
```

I don't believe you ever need to store a number larger than n^2 for this algorithm. It should be easy to modify such that it removes the ttmath related aspects, if you don't want to use those headers.

You can find the details of the mathematics online by looking up [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation), if you care about it.

Comment: Its not the a^b but (a^b) = n and then nCr % P for all r

Comment: I was a little confused by that part...what is "nCr" exactly?

Comment: nCr is number of ways of choosing r from n objects. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: I didn't know that other alternatives to gmp actually eist. This might be license-wise a more corporate friendly alternative. I wonder if it is optimized as well as gmp, however

Answer (score 1):

If we have to calcuate nCr mod p(where p is a prime), we can calculate factorial mod p and then use modular inverse to find nCr mod p. If we have to find nCr mod m(where m is not prime), we can factorize m into primes and then use Chinese Remainder Theorem(CRT) to find nCr mod m.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<vector>

/* This function calculates (a^b)%MOD */
long long pow(int a, int b, int MOD)
{
    long long x=1,y=a; 
    while(b > 0)
    {
        if(b%2 == 1)
        {
            x=(x*y);
            if(x>MOD) x%=MOD;
        }
        y = (y*y);
        if(y>MOD) y%=MOD; 
        b /= 2;
    }
    return x;
}

/*  Modular Multiplicative Inverse
    Using Euler's Theorem
    a^(phi(m)) = 1 (mod m)
    a^(-1) = a^(m-2) (mod m) */
long long InverseEuler(int n, int MOD)
{
    return pow(n,MOD-2,MOD);
}

long long C(int n, int r, int MOD)
{
    vector<long long> f(n + 1,1);
    for (int i=2; i<=n;i++)
        f[i]= (f[i-1]*i) % MOD;
    return (f[n]*((InverseEuler(f[r], MOD) * InverseEuler(f[n-r], MOD)) % MOD)) % MOD;
}

int main()
{    
    int n,r,p;
    while (~scanf("%d%d%d",&n,&r,&p))
    {
        printf("%lld\n",C(n,r,p));
    }
}
```

Here, I've used long long int to stote the number.

Answer (score 0):

In many. many cases in these coding competitions, the idea is that you don't actually calculate these big numbers, but figure out how to answer the question without calculating it. For example:

```
What are the last ten digits of 1,000,000! (factorial)?
```

It's a number with over five million digits. However, I can answer that question without a computer, not even using pen and paper. Or take the question: What is (2014^2014) modulo 153? Here's a simple way to calculate this in C:

```
int modulo = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 2014; ++i) modulo = (modulo * 2014) % 153;
```

Again, you avoided doing a calculation with a 6,000 digit number. (You can actually do this considerably faster, but I'm not trying to enter a competition).